# Issue with Database views in Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio, ado.net

I am working on a web application using entity framework and MySql. I have created some views and tables in my database but unfortunately ADO.Net data modal is not including the views. I have recreated my data modal but still views are missing. I have applied several solutions which i have found on different forums some one was suggesting to restart visual studio, Even some people was asking to restart the PC. but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have managed to solve this problem by adding a primary key column in my select statement.It was obvious that we must need a primary key to add our table in modal but as views have no primary key that's why i was confused. In short we must have to include at least one primary key column of a table in select statement.

Comment: Funny you found the answer at exact same time as posting the question :D

Comment: Actually i have just shared my experience here because i think it could be helpful for some one.

Comment: How do you add a primary key in a select statement?

Comment: @GertArnold Simply include your primary key column in select statement. I have also updated the answer as it was ambiguous previously.

Comment: The question and answer could use some sample code to be really helpful.